# Which one is correct "I have produced" or "I have Submitted"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-usage

Which one is correct "I have produced" or "I have Submitted"?
I need to write a letter to take my certificates previously I *submitted*/ produced certificates at the time of joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends - if they held onto your certificates after joining, then **submitted** would be correct. If you merely had to show them the certificates when you joined but you retained them then **produced** would be correct.